# PHP Xampp Error

Tags: php

```
<?php 

$Servername="localhost";
$Username="root";
$Password="";
$dbname="db_unity";

$connection=new mysqli($Servername,$Username,$Password,$dbname);

if(!$connection){

die("connection failed".mysqli_connect_error());

    }

else
{

    echo "connected";
} 

}
?>
```

Hello to everyone.When i write this code in sublime Text i have this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\unity\connection.php on line 22
```

Please help Why?!!!!!

Comment: You have 2 `{` and 3 `}` so you have an extra `}` :) The rule of thumb for curly braces is that they should be of equal pairs. no more no less :)

Comment: there is extra '}' at the end of file before end of PHP tag '?>'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP parse/syntax errors; and how to solve them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Answer (score 1):

You have a extra `}` at the end. the correct code would be

```
<?php 

$Servername="localhost";
$Username="root";
$Password="";
$dbname="db_unity";

$connection=new mysqli($Servername,$Username,$Password,$dbname);

if(!$connection){
    die("connection failed".mysqli_connect_error());

} else {
    echo "connected";
} 

?>
```

Also, be sure if you need that closing `?>` tag. It's a good practice to not close the php tag unless it's required.

Comment: Thanks...It works!

Comment: Great!. If I answered your question, please mark it as such.

Comment: Should of voted to close typos.. This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced **or a simple typographical error**. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.. or as a dupe of [PHP parse/syntax errors; and how to solve them.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them/18092308#18092308)

Comment: @LawrenceCherone My duplicate flag for this was disputed.